# How can I access variables from another class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, import

There is probably a very simple solution for this but I can't get it working.

I have got multiple classes in my Cocoa file. In one of the classes `class1` I create a variable that I need to use in another class `class2` as well. Is there a simple way to import this variable in `class2`?

Comment: “I have got multiple classes in my Cocoa file.” The usual way is to create one pair of files (MyClass.h, MyClass.m) for each class. You can do this by right-clicking on a group in the project and clicking Add File. You'll create the .m, and the .h will come along for free.

Comment: Directly accessing instance variables is a very bad idea. Use properties, and either synthesize the accessors or write your own. Direct variable access breaks things like KVO and bindings on Mac OS X, and it's not good OO practice.

Answer (score 15):

You can either make the variable public, or make it into a property.  For example, to make it public:

```
@interface Class1
{
@public
    int var;
}
// methods...
@end

// Inside a Class2 method:
Class1 *obj = ...;
obj->var = 3;
```

To make it a property:

```
@interface Class1
{
    int var;  // @protected by default
}
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int var;
// methods...
@end

@implementation Class1
@synthesize var;
...
@end

// Inside a Class2 method:
Class1 *obj = ...;
obj.var = 3;  // implicitly calls [obj setVar:3]
int x = obj.var;  // implicitly calls x = [obj var];
```

Comment: The property approach is far better, IMHO

Answer (score 5):

You could expose the variable in class2 as a property. If class1 has a reference to class2, class1 can then see the variable. Honestly, though, it sounds like you're a beginner to both Objective-C and object oriented programming. I recommend you read up more on both.

[Here is a place](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html) to start for object oriented programming with Objective-C.

Comment: Is "stackoverflow.com" only for the advanced users? How to define who is the beginner, and who is not. The guy did not give the question where to learn objective-C.

Comment: Honestly agree with @DariusMiliauskas :P

Comment: Stackoverflow is here for everyone and I believe the question makes sense and it can help others who might search for an answer to the above question!

Answer (score 3):

try making a file that holds your variables that need to be accessed throughout the app.

```
extern NSString *stringVariable;

@interface GlobalVariables

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *stringVariable;    

@end
```

and in the GlobalVariables.m file add

```
#import "GlobalVariables.h"

@implements GlobalVariables

@synthesize stringVariable;

NSString *stringVariable;

@end
```

And then as long as you import GlobalVariables.h into which ever .m files you need to access that variable in you can assign and access anywhere throughout your program.

**EDIT**

My answer that I have given above is differently not the way I would go about doing this now.
It would be more like

```
@interface MyClass

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myVariable;

@end
```

then in the .m file

```
@implementation MyClass

@sythesize = myVariable = _myVariable; // Not that we need to do this anymore

@end
```

Then in another class in some method I would have

```
// .....
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClass setMyVariable:@"My String to go in my variable"];
// .....
```

Comment: [[MyClass alloc] init] will give a new instance!

Answer (score 0):

In "XCode" you need to make import, create object by declaring it as the property, and then use "object.variable" syntax. The file "Class2.m" would look in the following way:

```
#import Class2.h
#import Class1.h;

@interface Class2 ()
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) Class1 *class1;
...
@end

@implementation Class2

//accessing the variable from balloon.h
...class1.variableFromClass1...;

...
@end
```

Thanks! :-)