# access to property of another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

How can I access to ViewController property from another class ? 
(the ViewController was created by XCode)

this is code of ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate; //il delegate disponibile per tutta la classe
    int numPag; //indice array (sulle pagine html da visualizzare)

    NSString *path;
    NSURL *baseURL;

    NSString *file;
    NSString *contentFile;

}


- (IBAction)sottrai:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)aggiungi:(id)sender;



@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *valore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *web;

@end
```

thanks!

[EDIT]

I use Xcode 4.3.2 and the code of AppDelegate.m not find something like:

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Now, I put in the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(into AppDelegate.m) this code:

```
    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

[viewController.web loadHTMLString:contentFile baseURL:baseURL];
```

adding in the file AppDelegate.h the variable viewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    NSArray *pageInItalian;
    NSArray *pageInEnglish;
    UIViewController *viewController; 

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageInLanguage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;



@end
```

I did it correctly? the error is: Property 'web' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

Answer (score 2):

I think this post might answer your question

[How can I access variables from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658697/how-can-i-access-variables-from-another-class)

You need to make your variable accessible from foreign classes (with @property and @synthesize) and then your foreign class need to know your instance of ViewController

**[EDIT]**

In your AppDelegate.m, there must be a line like this one :

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This is where your ViewController is instantiate. From there, you can access every property of your ViewController.

**[EDIT]**

You need to add the following at the beginning of your implementation

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize web;
```

Comment: how do I take the instance of ViewController? The viewcontroller was created by XCode in the code. Can I instantiate it?

Comment: I have done this. where am I doing wrong?...I can not allocate "ViewController" only understands "UIViewController". Perhaps this is the error