# How to access a property of a viewcontroller from another one? iPhone

Tags: iphone, properties, uiviewcontroller

I define a property in the viewcontroller A

```
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL updateOnServer;
```

and also synthesize it, give it values and then I try to access this variable from another viewcontroller B like this

```
  A * view = [[A alloc] init];

  if (view.updateOnServer)
```

but it isn't working. updateOnServer is always NO.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: you have to figure the meaning of "instance" first

Comment: first set value in this updateOnServer

Comment: I set value. I wrote this. :)

Comment: @Maria I Have made a sample project according to your description ... and it is working smoothly .. giving me values of YES and NO

Comment: @SunTzu I will look more attentively. Maybe it is another problem.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `updateOnServer` within viewControllerA, and in viewControllerB you create a new instance of `updateOnServer` which you haven't set to anything. So it takes the default value of BOOL which is NO.

Kindly look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658697/how-can-i-access-variables-from-another-class) for possible solution.

You have many ways to do :  make the variable global, static, singleton, pass as an argument, post as notification.

Comment: and how could I access the instance of viewcontrollerB?, so that I don't create a new instance.:)

Comment: many ways, make it global, static, singleton, pass as an argument, post as notification.

Comment: How do you go from A to B ?

Comment: @rdurand : Kindly mention the recipient :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : oops, my bad. Anyways, seems like your answer solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to save and retrieve information of variable ,although not prefered some time is NSUserDefaults.
 
Use NSUserDefaults Check Out the [Link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/) for how to use NSUserDefaults.
Or you can  declare Global Variable.

Comment: There is never a good reason to use NSUserDefaults to pass variables between classes especially in a situation like this where delegation or notifications are a clear choice.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I agree with you  and ,thats y also mention not prefered but simple to use  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a singleton class as follows:

Create a new class as follows:

```
ServerCheck.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ServerCheck : NSObject
{
    BOOL updateOnServer;
}
@property (nonatomic) BOOL updateOnServer;

+ (id)sharedSingletonController;
@end

ServerCheck.m

#import "ServerCheck.h"

@implementation ServerCheck
@synthesize updateOnServer
+(ServerCheck*)sharedSingletonController{

    static ServerCheck *sharedSingletonController;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!sharedSingletonController){
            sharedSingletonController = [[ServerCheck alloc]init];
        }
    }

    return sharedSingletonController;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

        }
    return self;
}

@end
```

You can access the BOOL value as follows:

```
ServerCheck *serverData = [ServerCheck sharedSingletonController];
serverData.updateOnServer = YES;
```