# Passing a running float to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using MBProgressHUD from GitHub and would like to pass the running progress float to another class.

In Class A :

```
-(void)methodName
{
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myProgressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
- (void)myProgressTask
{
    HUD.progress = progress;
}
```

In Class B :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    expectedLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    currentLength = 0;
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    currentLength += [data length];
    float progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
    NSLog(@"%f", progress);
}
```

Need to pass the "float progress" from Class B to Class A's method: "myProgressTask"

NSLog:

```
2013-02-27 15:23:14.006 [8209:c07] 0.161726
2013-02-27 15:23:14.329 [8209:c07] 0.253171
2013-02-27 15:23:14.718 [8209:c07] 0.436063
2013-02-27 15:23:15.941 [8209:c07] 0.527508
2013-02-27 15:23:16.230 [8209:c07] 0.618954
2013-02-27 15:23:16.238 [8209:c07] 0.710400
2013-02-27 15:23:16.614 [8209:c07] 0.893291
2013-02-27 15:23:16.615 [8209:c07] 0.984736
2013-02-27 15:23:16.618 [8209:c07] 1.000000
```

Hope you can help! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Voting to close, as similar questions with minor changes are already there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063078/how-to-access-a-property-of-a-viewcontroller-from-another-one-iphone/15063118#15063118

Comment: that question is nothing similar to mine...

Comment: Similarity is passing value from one class to other. isn't it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It is, indeed - this is the type of question that rises multiple times a day, usually with the title "passing data between view controllers" and with the cause of OP not understanding the difference between a class and an instance of a class. No magic here.

Comment: Well this isnt just a float.. its a running float.. no answer here solved my problem.. because if I log the float its just 0.. not running at all, just sitting there..

Stop moaning and move to another question if you cant help.. really..

Comment: just uses 0 instead of the progress between 0 and 1..
If i log it, only 0 appears, where as it should appear as I stated above. Running from 0 to 1. But anyway, save your ignorance, the question is answered :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this method to :

```
- (void)myProgressTask:(float)progress
{
    HUD.progress = progress;
}
```

In your class B change :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    currentLength += [data length];
    float progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
    NSLog(@"%f", progress);
    ClassA obj = [[ClassA alloc] init]; //Put autorelease if you are not using ARC.
    [obj myProgressTask:progress];
}
```

Comment: this feels like the right way and a lot easier, but it doesnt work :(

Comment: I used this and figured it out! Thanks man! Got it running, just need to place it in the correct place :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is use of protocol. See in XCode 4 example of Utility application

In Class A header:

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController <ClassBDelegate>

@property float yourFloat;
```

In Class A implementation:

```
- (void)loadClassB
{
    ClassB *classB = [ClassB new];
    classB.delegate = self; 
}
```

Class B header file:

```
@class ClassB;

@protocol ClassBDelegate
- (void)callbackMethod;
@end

@interface ClassB : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ClassBDelegate> delegate;



@end
```

Class B implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    float newFloat = self.delegate.yourFloat; // <- the assignment occurs here
    [self.delegate callbackMethod];
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense.. Example please?

Comment: In your case you shouldn't pass the variable. You have to use the same variable of **class A** in class B via delegate

Comment: ERROR: classB.delegate = self; No setter method "setDelegate:" for assignment to property. ?

Comment: Did you set delegate in ClassA header?

Comment: In this line @interface ClassA : UIViewController <ClassBDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of following:

1. Make the variable global
2. static
3. singleton
4. pass as an argument
5. post as notification.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063078/how-to-access-a-property-of-a-viewcontroller-from-another-one-iphone/15063118#15063118).

*NOTE : Globals in on top of the list because of new programmer find it easy, once they are used to obj-c, they know which is best and when.*

Comment: Can you please show or guide me how to do 1?

Comment: Pleeease avoid globals.

Comment: Globals in on top of the list because of new programmer find it easy, once they are used to obj-c, they know which is best and when. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem. I would use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Make `progress` a property of `Class B`. Then change:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    currentLength += [data length];
    //float progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
    self.progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
    //NSLog(@"%f", progress);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.progress);
}
```

In `class A` then register for Key-Value observation of `classB.progress`. You can do this in init of `class A`.

```
[classB_object_reference addObserver:self
                          forKeyPath:@"progress"
                             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                             context:nil];
```

Add this method to `class A`:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    //do whatever you want here with the new value of classB_object.progress
}
```