# how to access instance Variable in another class

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I have instance variable in class1 that save integer value (number of cell in tableview) and I want used this variable in another class (for example class2) but I don't know used which syntax???

Comment: obj->instance_var = 123;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063078/how-to-access-a-property-of-a-viewcontroller-from-another-one-iphone/15063118#15063118

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, you re-direct to your answer, that re-directs to another thread. I wonder what SO's recursion depth is…

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Actually the answer next to mine is good one. Even I linked and got accepted. and there are some protected(retain) posts. What if a retain-cycle forms :D

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: you mean the NSUserDefault approach? that is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

« If possible use member variable.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject  
{
    int score;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int score;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize score;
@end

//access
MyClass *object = [MyClass alloc] init];
object.score = 99;
```

« Also you can use NSUserDefault

```
// Snippet used to save your highscore in the prefs.
int highScore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


// Snippet used to get your highscore from the prefs.
highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
```

Comment: guys I have in class1 (class1 is UITableViewController Class) delegate method :"didSelectRowAtIndexPath" in this method using instance variable like this : j=(indexPath.row)+1 and I want use this value in another class

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

For example: You want to pass a String from `Class1` to `Class2`.

Create String in Class2 first and define it as property as in `Class2.h`:

```
NSString *classTwoString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *classTwoString;
```

In `Class2.m`:

```
@synthesize classTwoString;
```

Then, for example, you want to pass the String when a button in `Class1` is touched. In its action (create `IBAction`, link it with the button's `touchesUpInside`), you can set it to get the instance of your second class, for example:

```
Class2 *class2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];    
class2.classTwoString= classOneString;
```

I suggest the above method.

Using `NSUserDefaults` - may lose the value stored if the application crashes.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use properties.  Here's an example:

Class1.h

```
@property int myValue
```

Class1.m

```
self.myValue = 2
```

Class2.m

```
int v = instanceOfClass1.myValue
```

Here's a link to a tutorial about using properties: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial

Comment: Ah, I get the -1 now: if `class1` (the first "controller", if you will) created `class2`, then an instance of `class2` would not (or rather, **should** not) have know about `class1` (because it would be it's parent).

Comment: IMHO, if `class1` created `class2` (hence, `class1` is the parent and `class2` is the child), `class1` should set a property on `class2` (not the other way around, as you show...)

Comment: The question didn't specify scope or how the references between classes were made.  Class2, even if it were the child, could easily know about Class1 using a delegate pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
@implementation classA {
    int v;
}

id x = [[classA alloc] init];
x->v = 123;
```

Googled "objective c instance variable" and found this article.
http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/04/objective-c-tuesdays-instance-variables.html

Comment: This is old school and isn't recommended/done anymore... instead, you should create and set a `property` on `classA` in your example... (I didn't downvote though... just IMHO).

Comment: I just answer the question, no thing more.