# Define UIabel in appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So,at the last stages of this project I decided I wanted notifications.
The problem is, I have a `UILabel` set up in my MainViewController, it gets its values from the input there, and I need to use those values for the time interval on my notification setup which gets called when the app gets backgrounded. (Code located in `Appdelegate.m`)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date]
                     dateByAddingTimeInterval:[self.labelone.text intValue] * 60];
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                    init];
if (notifyAlarm)
{
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Staff meeting in 30 minutes";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the `UILabel` (`self.labelone`) universally, but no matter what I try, it throws up errors. Any help or tips would be very appreciated!

Comment: Your `labelone` is in `MainViewController` so you cant access it by `self.....` in `Appdelegate`.

Comment: I thought that, but what do i do? labelone isnt recognised at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063078/how-to-access-a-property-of-a-viewcontroller-from-another-one-iphone/15063118#15063118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the background notification in your MainViewController by registering for a notification through NSNotificationCenter in viewDidLoad method of MainViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

When the app enters the background, your MainViewController will call the selector willEnterBackground:, so you'll want to set that up:

```
- (void)willEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ...you can now access self.labelone
}
```

In the MainViewController viewDidUnload method, remove the observer of that notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: I'm going to try this now, thanks for the heads up. I wasnt able to find any good resources for `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: So basically with a little tweaking this should work perfectly, and means I don't clog up my delegate. Thanks for the crash course in `NSNotification` @daltonclaybrook!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `AppDelegate`, create a `UILabel` weak property called `timeIntervalLabel`.

Then inside `MainViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` simply do:

```
AppDelegate *d = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
d.timeIntervalLabel = self.labelone
```

Finally, inside your `applicationDidEnterBackground` you can use `self.timeIntervalLabel`

Comment: Per MVC standards, it's not considered good practice to access UI elements from your App Delegate, which is regarded as part of your model. This should be handled exclusively from the View Controller.

Comment: Thankyou, I haven't seen it explained so easily anywhere before. Just wondering though, it still throws an error of not having label one defined. If i define it, is it still going to be updated on AppDelegate or will it start acting on its own accord? EDIT: I added the property back into the view controller and it works as intended

Comment: Yes obviously the label thing is wrong in many ways but I was trying to solve his specific problem with minimal changes. It is indeed totally wrong to have app-specific information managed through a UI component.