# Objective-C: Accessing a variable in another class

Tags: objective-c, class, poptoviewcontroller

In my app, I am trying to access a variable that is set in one class (ClassC), and then pops off 2 views to ClassA, and that view (ClassA), needs to access that variable set in ClassC. Let's see if I can make this a little clearer:

A button in my ClassC calls this method:

```
-(IBAction) mapItBtn:(id)sender
{
    MapAnnotation* target = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:building.Name subTitle:@"" Coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(building.Latitude, building.Longitude)];

    DIRlat = building.Latitude;
    DIRlon = building.Longitude;

    [mapUI removeAnnotations:mapUI.annotations];
    [mapUI addAnnotation:target];
    [mapUI selectAnnotation:target animated:YES];
    [[mapUI viewForAnnotation:target] setCanShowCallout:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center=target.coordinate;
    region.span.latitudeDelta=mapUI.region.span.latitudeDelta;
    region.span.longitudeDelta=mapUI.region.span.longitudeDelta;

    [mapUI setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

    [mapUI setHidden:NO];

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 3)] animated:YES];
 }
```

Once the last line is completed and the app `popsToViewController:...objectAtIndex:...-3`, that view (ClassA) needs to access the values of `DIRlat` and `DIRlon` in ClassC. The class importing structure is ClassA imports ClassB which imports ClassC.

Any suggestions on how to best accomplish this task would be immensely appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Things I have tried, and have been unsuccessful:

Creating a variable in ClassA, and then in ClassC I have `@implementation ClassA` and `@synthesize AVariable`, however this led to a Parse Issue where ClassA resulted in reading ClassB as an unknown type.

The opposite actions of the above code, as in creating a variable in ClassC, and then `@implementation ClassC` in ClassA. This resulted in a circular dependency (Mach-O linker error).

The thing that I am currently trying to accomplish is to make a singleton class, however since I have had no experience with it, progress is going slowly.

Comment: There are dozens of questions here on this subject. Do some looking around, starting with the sidebar ----->

Comment: That is what I have been doing over the last few hours, I have tried making a public variable, various ways of `@implementation ClassA` in `ClassC` as well as `@implementation ClassC` in `ClassA`. Thank you for your suggestion, I'll continue going through previous S.O. topics.

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you tried, why you thought that would work, and what goes wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access variables from another class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658697/how-can-i-access-variables-from-another-class)

Comment: Okay guys thanks for letting me know that there are other S.O. topics on this, I know that there are other questions similar to this one. I have gone through many of them and tried their suggestions as best as I can as it relates to my code. I have also edited my question to include all of the things I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** Solved my problem by creating a Singleton class by following a guide found [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/).

**Edit:** Showing the code solution:

`MKLocationManagerSingleton.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MKLocationManagerSingleton : NSObject {
    double MKlat;
    double MKlon;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double MKlat;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double MKlon;
+ (id)sharedManager;
@end
```

`MKLocationManagerSingleton.m`

```
#import "MKLocationManagerSingleton.h"
@implementation MKLocationManagerSingleton
@synthesize MKlat, MKlon;
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MKLocationManagerSingleton *sharedMKLocationManagerSingleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMKLocationManagerSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMKLocationManagerSingleton;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {   
}
@end
```

And requested the values for MKlat and MKlon with:

```
MKLocationManager *sharedManager = [MKLocationManager sharedManager];
destination.latitude = sharedManager.MKlat;
destination.longitude = sharedManager.MKlon;
```